# Is there a way to get list of local variables declared in C source code

Tags: c, parsing

I need a method to extract list of all local declared variables inside a function in a C source code with their line number. Is there a possible way.. I need this list to add and intialize stub variables after the local variable declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Within the context of a C program?

No. Local variables don't really "exist" in C code. They're all constructs made for the programmer's convenience. This is because humans are really bad at remembering random 64-bit numbers and variable length machine opcodes.

You can do this via external tools, but these don't work at compile time and can't alter the compiled code.

You're asking about "reflection", and C basically has *zero* reflection features. Either something is defined and compiles, or it isn't and it doesn't. There is no way to ask if some function or variable is defined and change the code's behaviour.

The only facility you have is `#define` macros for pre-processing, and while you can get exceptionally creative and devious with these, there are limits to what you can and, more importantly, should do.

Comment: @WhozCraig Good catch. Got C++ on the brain today.

Comment: Do you know any such external tool @tadman

Comment: It's far from clear what you're trying to achieve, so I'll ask: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I just need to define stub variables inside functions.This process is automated. I find list of all function definition in C source file and define stub variables inside each one of them. I use opening curly bracket as my index and added those variables.. But as these stub variables are defined prior to any other variable declaration I get syntax error.. So do you know any parser tool to get local variable declarations.. I tried using ctags tool but it just gives me global variables

Comment: Can you give some code for context?

Comment: func1
{
func_id=4;
int a ;
int b
}
correct one:

func1
{
int a;
int b;
fun_id=3
}

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. Does one map into the other? Are you actually asking "How can I declare a variable that represents the function's line number?" If so, `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` can help.

Comment: func1
{
func_id=4;
int a ;
int b
}
correct one:

func1
{
int a;
int b;
fun_id=3
}   Here fun_id=3 is stub variable which I need to add to all functions in a c source code.the first one gives syntax error. so I need to define fun_id=3 after the function declaration.So if I've a parser tool I could use that to get info of local variable declarations inside the function and add funid=3 after all other variable declaration..here defining funid=3 is an automated process. I use python code to insert funid=3 inside functions of C source file

Comment: Why `3`? What type should it be? What's the purpose of this? Can you do it with a macro? I'm trying to get to the root of this problem, not your proposed solution. What's the ultimate objective here?

Comment: Just for illustration I took 3..but I'm trying to add unique Id to each function and store them in Funid variable of type int. If Funid = 3 then it is a function with unique id as 3.

Comment: Unique per-file or globally? Per-file you could just use `__LINE__` but globally that will be...trickier.

Comment: No it is global.. I have to generate IDs for list of source files. So is there any parser tool to get this info

Comment: For tools you'll need to do your own research as understand the specifics of what you need is really hard over this channel. There's a lot of open-source options, though.

Comment: I don't get the value of modifying a global every time you enter a function. The value will only be useful up to the first function call, since all functions share the same global. You might conceivably find [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace) useful.